# Confused about protocols

Tags: ios, swift

I've got couple of classes that inherit from SKNode.
Both of them have a setup() method. They are pretty different from each other.

I've made a protocol like this:

```
protocol LevelProtocol {   
    func setup(level: Int)
}
```

and two of my classes look something like thes:

```
class Puzzle: SKNode, LevelProtocol {
    func setup(level: Int) {do something}

class Action: SKNode, LevelProtocol {
    func setup(level: Int) {do something}
```

And in my main class I need to use one of these classes in one variable.
How do I define this variable properly?

I've tried this:

```
var lvl: LevelProtocol
if myLevel > 5 {
    lvl = Puzzle()
else {
    lvl = Action()
}

lvl.setup(myLevel)
self.addChild(lvl)
```

But the compiler says that LevelProtocol is not convertible to SKNode
I know Im doing something wrong, just cannot understand what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really good in Swift but I think you could try `self.addChild(lvl as SKNode)`

Another solution:

Well, I think, then you need to redesign the inheritance. Try making class `Level` inheriting from `SKNode` and declare just one method `setup` there and leave its body empty. Then you create classes `Puzzle` and `Action` deriving from `Level` and having their own implementation of `setup`. Then your code is:

```
var lvl: Level
if myLevel > 5 {
  lvl = Puzzle()
}
else {
   lvl = Action()
}

lvl.setup(myLevel)
self.addChild(lvl)
```

Comment: Wont't work. It works if I try `self.addChild(lvl as Puzzle)` but that's just wrong.

Comment: Yeah It worked, thanks for the insight. I'll probably leave this question open for couple of days, maybe there still is a Protocol solution.